# grav Mac OS X plist setup

Tags: macos, plist

MI have just installed Grav locally and would like it to run as a daemon. Apparently on Macs that's done in `~/LauchAgents`

I have tried to setup the `.plist` but it's not working. As I am new to Macs I wondered if anyone knew how to setup a local service? Here is what I have so far...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>grav</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/bin/php</string>
      <string>~/grav/php -S system/router.php</string>
      <string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
      <string>--httpPort=8000</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: do you have some error message regarding your LaunchAgent in `/var/log/system.log`?

Comment: Have you tried using the full path `/Users/your-username/grav/php` instead of `~/grav/php` in the second argument? The tilde `~` is likely only valid in the shell, but not necessarily in other execution environments.

Comment: Also, it should be `~/Library/LaunchAgents`. Do you have the correct path?

Comment: I can find no error in the log and when I try to enable with `sudo launchctl enable ~/Library/LaunchAgents/grav.plist` I get the message, `Usage: launchctl enable <service-target>`

Comment: try just `launchctl enable grav`

Comment: still get `Usage: launchctl enable <service-target>`